# Exception in Struts 2.5.22 while start

Tags: logging, struts2, log4j2

I am getting following exceptions while starting tomcat server.  it seems like a log4j exception. I have just upgraded struts version to 2.5.22 from 2.5.20. Log4j-api-2.12.1 and log4j core is 2.13.2. Please suggest.

```
2020 1:41:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [struts2]
****java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.getStringProperty([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/util/Supplier;)Ljava/lang/String;****
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.BasicAuthorizationProvider.<init>(BasicAuthorizationProvider.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using different versions of Log4J-api and Log4J-core is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have different versions of jars for log4j-core and log4j-api. To manage dependency use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/).

add Maven [dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j/2.13.2/pom) to your project

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```